# Read csv from shell script and print the column header based on closest match to user input

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, csv, array

I Have a csv file. It has multiple columns. I want to develop a shell script which prompts the use for a numerical value, find the closest match in the csv and print the header of the column. For example

```
        Apple       orange      grape      berry


1       1.3         1.9         0.4         1.756

2       2.1.        3.3         6.6         0.964

3      0.444        1.364       1.1         3.6
```

If the user input is 3.4, then the closest value is 3.3 and the output should be " This is Orange"

Any thoughts on how can I accomplish this. (FYI - CSV is pretty large file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little inelegant but works

```
read -p "Enter a value .... " t
awk -v test=$t 'NR==1{min=1000;for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) head[i]=$i}
    NR>1 && NF>0{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++){diff=($i<test)?(test-$i):($i-test); if (diff<min) {min=diff; item=i-1} }}
    END{ print "Closest to "test" is "head[item]}' file
```

Output

```
Closest to 3.4 is orange
```

Comment: thank you. Whats the min=1000 doing here.

Comment: Just initialising the min value away from `NULL` and out of range of your likely matches.

Comment: this will not prompt the user for a input..right. can I make it prompt for an input value?